# jQuery Cycle fade duration

Tags: jquery

Using the jQuery Cycle plugin is it possible to change the length of the fade transition?

I know the length of time the slide is displayed can be controlled with the speed variable but is it possible to apply this to the actual fade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`timeout` sets the duration of each slide. 
`speed` sets the duration of the transitions.

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QpNnx/) that demonstrates the change in transition time.